# Combinatorics elementary question

Tags: combinatorics

A board has a red space, a blue space, and a yellow space. A checker is situated on the red space. On each move the checker is transferred to one of the other two spaces. In how many ways can one make a series of 11 moves which result in the checker returning to the red space?

I tried constructive counting but it sucks because you don't know where it ends on the 10th move. Other than that I don't know what to try, since casework looks ugly. Could you please show me a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Think of your red, blue, and yellow spaces as the numbers $0$, $1$, and $-1$ mod $3$.  Each move can thought of as adding $\pm1$ to your current position, starting from $0$.  If you make $p$ "$+1$" moves and $n=11-p$ "$-1$" moves, you wind up at $p-n=2p-11$ mod $3$, which is takes you back to the red square (position $0$) iff $p=1$, $4$, $7$, or $10$.  There are a total of

$${11\choose1}+{11\choose4}+{11\choose7}+{11\choose10}=11+330+330+11=682$$

ways to do this.

Comment: I don't really get it... could you explain?

Answer (score 1):

Let $r_n$, $b_n$, $y_n$ be the number of sequences of $n$ moves for which the checker ends on the red, blue, yellow space respectively. Then, we get the following recursive equations:

$r_{n+1} = b_n + y_n$

$b_{n+1} = r_n + y_n$

$y_{n+1} = r_n + b_n$

Do you see why these equations are true?

After $0$ moves (i.e. at the start) the checker is on the red square, so $r_0 = 1$, $b_0 = 0$, and $y_0 = 0$. Now, crank out the recursion to find $r_{11}$.

Note: It is easy to see that $b_n = y_n$ for all $n$, so you can actually collapse the recursive equations down to two first order recursions, or even one second order recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Let $r_m$ be the number of ways of being on the red space after $m$ moves and $n_m$ the number of ways of not being being on the red space.  You have $$r_0=1$$ $$n_0=0$$ $$r_{m+1}=n_m$$ $$n_{m+1}=2r_m+n_m$$ and you want to find $r_{11}$. You could just run the recurrences.

An alternative approach would be to note that $n_{m+1}=2n_{m-1}+n_m$ and so $r_{m+2}=2r_m+r_{m+1}$, starting with $r_0=1$ and $r_1=0$.